# Smoothing sharp edge

Tags: vertices, smooth

I have this shape imported from an svg file.
[image]

But I'm not able to make that sharp edge smooth. When I use Bevel, I get weird behaviour from the final vertex:
[image]

Clamp overlap solves the issue but doen't allow me to control the weight of the bevel.
I've tried subdividing, scaling, adding inset faces and subdiving surface but everytime I get extra faces from this vertes:
[image]

Sorry, I can't add the .blend file but I'm not allowed to.

I can assure you that I've tried any answer related to this I've found here in this Q&A site but nothing helped.
I know it's a beginner question but any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have enough space on the mesh to work with.

No matter what, the width of the bevel modifier is exceeding the width of the geometry on the mesh.

[image]

The only I can really think of to fix it is to select all the exterior faces and use Alt+ S to inflate it slightly. Give the mesh a bit more room to work with.

[image]